# Which is the correct pronunciation of Han in Star Wars?

Tags: character, star-wars

The release of "The Force Awakens" reminded me of something I found confusing in both the older and newest Star Wars movies -- the pronunciation of Han Solo's first name.

It seems that some characters pronounce Han like you'd pronounce the first part of the word **Han**d. Others pronounce it like the first part of the country **Hon**duras.

Which is correct?

I don't remember hearing him say his own name (though he probably did at some point) so I'm unclear on this.

Comment: *"Which is correct?"*  You say TomaRto I say TomaYto.  Who is 'correct'?  It's all just accents to me, even Han's way of saying his own name is simply him saying it with *his accent.*  Does that make his way of saying his name any more valid than anyone else's way of saying it?

Comment: Hans. The S is invisible but not silent.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes, it does. The pronunciation of a name should be deferred to the person with said name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's pronounced HAHN Solo.

You can hear his own pronunciation of his name when he introduces himself at the very start of this clip:

Comment: He pronounces Falcon funny too.

Comment: Falcon is another 'tomato' word, US F**a**lcon, UK F**o**lcon, though Ford makes a decent showing of getting it closer to F**o**lcon in that clip.

Comment: @Tetsujin UK F**aw**lcon, I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

George Lucas, the creator of Star Wars clearly thinks that it's Han with a hard 'a' (rhymes with "***han***d").

It's not entirely clear why every other character mispronounces it throughout the film series.

Comment: Now try to tell all those Lucas-haters that he has any kind of authority on that matter (but of course he has, he's created him). ;-)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - Oh, I expect this to be a downvote magnet. It's not "fanboy approved" to suggest that Lucas had any involvement with the making of Star Wars.

Comment: Only the British actors mispronounce it.... (i.e. pronounce it in the British way)

Comment: @geraldEdgar - over-trained, I guess. That's what comes of hiring respected British thespians for low-budget sf movies.

Answer (score 1):

Han is pronounced with a soft "a".  Like "Hahn" (rhymes with "con"), as opposed to "Hann" (rhymes with "Ann").

[image]

Comment: … but, but… you can't use 'sounds like' comparisons, because you don't know the accent of the person reading the comparison. In British English, there's no way I could torture the word 'con' to sound anything *like* Han.